# css 100% stretched table inside a table-row fail in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, tablerow, stretching

The problem:
Stretching a table 100% width/height inside a table-row doesn't work in IE.
Why?!

Here's the code (http://jsfiddle.net/GBsay/2/):

html:

```
<body>
    <div id="row">
        <div id="table">
           this table should be 100% width/height, green color<br/>
           It works in ANY browser except IE.<br/>
           WHY?!
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
html, body {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
body {
    display:table;
}
#row {
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#f00;
}
#table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#0f0;
}
```

This code works in all browsers except IE (7,8,9,10). 
Anyone knows how to fix this using only css?

Comment: Tested in 7,8,9,10 - neither works. So basically it doesn't work in IE at all.

Comment: If someone else comes across this I aws having exactly the same problem and solved it by setting a min-height (can be anything, 1px) on the parent div (the one with display:table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wonderful beauty of Internet Explorer, is a test of patience for many developers, however the solution is as follows

```
 
html, body {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#table {
    position: relative;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:lightgreen;
}

body {

}
#row {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: static;
    display:block;
    background:lightblue;
    text-align:center;
    float: center;
    top:100%;
}
```